# Как сделать ветку последовательных вопросов и записи ответов на них в боте telegram на google apps script?

Tags: telegram-bot, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

уважаемое сообщество!
Подскажите, как сделать массив с последовательными вопросами и записать ответы в массив чтобы передать его в гугл таблицу?
Я первый раз работаю с кодом, не имею навыков и знаний, вооружился интернетом и стал собирать бота для собственных нужд в самой таблице. Сейчас мой бот после нажатия кнопки "Записать" [(работа кнопки в боте)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0kBf.png), записывает в правильные ячейки, но записывает саму команду, а не значения которые мне нужны [(так выглядит запись в таблице, до бота этого записывал "вручную")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT054.png). Как бы сделать чтобы он после нажатия кнопки "Записать", задавал вопрос и ждал моего ответа и записывал уже ответ, а затем задавал следующий вопрос и также записывал ответ?
Мой код функции doPost:

```
function doPost(e) {
  const contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents),
    contents_s = JSON.stringify(contents);

  const msg = contents.message,
    chatType = msg.chat.type,
    messageText = (msg.text || '') + (msg.caption || ''), //или само сообщение или подпись к файлу / фото
    user = msg.from.hasOwnProperty('username') ? msg.from.username : '',
    userFirstName = msg.from.first_name,
    userLastName = msg.from.last_name,
    chat_id = msg.chat.id;
  src_msg = msg.hasOwnProperty('reply_to_message') ? msg.reply_to_message.text : '';
  src_sender = msg.hasOwnProperty('reply_to_message') ? msg.reply_to_message.from.username : '';

  const checkPm = chatType == 'private',
    chat = checkPm ? '' : msg.chat.username,   //если отправлено не ЛС, то добавляем username чата
    chatTitle = checkPm ? '' : msg.chat.title; //и название чата

  const checkFile = msg.hasOwnProperty('document'),
    fileId = checkFile ? msg.document.file_id : msg.hasOwnProperty('photo') ? msg.photo[1].file_id : '',
    fileMime = checkFile ? msg.document.mime_type : '',
    fileName = checkFile ? msg.document.file_name : '';

    if (messageText =="/start"){
      var message = "Выберите один из пунктов меню"
     sendkeyboard(chat_id, message, KEYBOARDMENU);
    }
    if (messageText =="Записать"){
      var message = "Введите значение:"
      sendMessage(chat_id, message)
      writeMessage(messageText)
    }
    if (messageText =="Удалить"){
     var message = "Последняя запись удалена"
     sendMessage(chat_id, message)
    }
    if (messageText =="Отчет"){
     var message = "Выберите месяц"
     sendMessageInlineMenu(chat_id, message, INLINE)
    }
 log(chat_id, user, userFirstName, userLastName, messageText, contents_s, chat, chatTitle, fileId, fileMime, fileName, src_msg, src_sender)
}
```

Функция writeMessage

```
function writeMessage(messageText) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("BOT"),
    data = [[new Date(),messageText]];
    range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Искал в интернете не нашел. Находит только документацию, я пробовал под себя внедрить какие-то функции но у меня ничего не вышло.

Comment: Используйте паттерн машины состояний. [XState](https://xstate.js.org/) работает в скриптах из коробки. Конфигурацию можно загружать непосредственно из Таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сделать цепочку сообщений.

Допустим, после того, как Вы написали боту слово "Потратил" - бот должен "запомнить", что Вы его спрашивали. Например, через [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service?hl=en).

Т.е., общая логика такая:

1. Вы пишете боту кодовое слово "Записать"
2. Бот заносит в память Ваш ID и Ваш этап общения - в данном случае, это ожидание вашего ответа. И отвечает Вам "Что записать?"
3. Вы ему пишите что нужно - и он записывает это в ячейку, уведомляя Вас об этом. Попутно обнуляя ваш этап общения.